# Is there a Vector3 implementation for OS X? Preferably Objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, macos

So I'd love to have a class that is basically identical to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb324325(v=vs.85).aspx

Does this exist w/in OS X in some framework? After Googling around a bit I wasn't able to find anything concrete, just references to NSMutableArray which obviously won't work.

Thanks!

Comment: I take it the various Vector operations are desired? What about the operations requiring a matrix [transformation]? (E.g. "not just a tuple")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SMatrix](http://project-mathlibs.web.cern.ch/project-mathlibs/sw/5_22_00/html/SMatrixDoc.html) has a vector Vector class that can be useful. If you are after a space-like 3-vector, then [GenVector](http://project-mathlibs.web.cern.ch/project-mathlibs/sw/5_22_00/html/Vector.html) has generic 3-vectors and points, plus 2D, 3D and 4D operations and transformations. GenVector is more suited to physics, so the vector dimensions and a lot of the available operations have a specific meaning. SMatrix is more generic and supports some vector and linear algebra operations.

Comment: How can I view those page?  They both say error access denied :/

Comment: @Geesu oops! I must have has some authentication going on in my browser. I'll try to find a mirror, but it might be a while. I'm not involved in those projects anymore...

Comment: @Geesu can you see the pages now? I have asked for the permissions to be set back to public.

Comment: These days, you can just use GLKit's GLKVector3.